# UDIM texture correct in "Material Preview Shading" in viewport but different in "Rendered Shading" (Cycles)

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

I set up a UDIM texture and got it working right when looking at it in "Material Preview" mode in the viewport. I'm wrapping it around a sphere and the UV map has been adjusted to cover the entire UDIM texture in the UV editor.
[image: Material Preview Shading]
When swapping to "Rendered" mode in the viewport, and when I try rendering, the texture turns mostly white, with a quarter of it turning black.
[image]
I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong. I have a sun light source, and adjusting the intensity doesn't change anything.
[image]
I'm using a UDIM texture here as my project needs to be zoomed in close at various places, so I obtained high-res satellite images and compiled them into a large texture, then split it into 4k UDIM tiles.

I'd appreciate any help I can get in figuring out this issue.

Comment: I should add that I pulled it out of my shader setup while troubleshooting. sending the texture through a principled BSDF doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: Also, it works fine in eevee, but the rest of my shader need's cycles so I'll be investigating it further. Also implies that this isn't a UV issue afterall, but a shader issue. I'll update the original post accordingly.

Comment: I was unable to resolve the issue in my existing file, but starting from scratch in a new file resolved the issue.